# BlackBerry - How to add clickEvent (setChangeListener) to ListField in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I'm using `ListField` in Blackberry and unable to apply the `row.setChangeListener`.
Can anybody please help me?
Here is my code,

```
Friendship objFriendship = new Friendship();
  friends = objFriendship.FetchFriends(AATTGlobals.CURRENT_USER.getUserID()); 
  rows = new Vector();
  for (int x = 0; x < friends.length; x++) {
  String UserName = friends[x].getUserName();
  ProfilePicture = MISC.FetchUserProfilePicture(friends[x].getProfilePicturePath());
  String Location = friends[x].getLocation();
  TableRowManager row = new TableRowManager();
  row.add(new BitmapField(ProfilePicture));
  LabelField task = new LabelField(UserName,DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS)
   {
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
         graphics.setColor(0x0099CCFF);
         super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };
  task.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD));
  row.add(task);
  row.add(new LabelField(Location,DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS)
   {
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
     graphics.setColor(0x0099CCFF);
     super.paint(graphics);
    } 
  }
  );
row.setChangeListener( new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        Dialog.alert("Row Clicked #");
    }
});
```

No any error message but `setChangeListener` doesn't fire, here is `TableRowManager`

```
Private class TableRowManager extends Manager {
    public TableRowManager() {
    super(0);
}
public void drawRow(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
   layout(width, height);
   setPosition(x, y);
   g.pushRegion(getExtent());
   subpaint(g);
   g.setColor(0x0099CCFF);
   g.drawLine(0, 0, getPreferredWidth(), 0);
   g.popContext();
  }
  protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
   int fontHeight = Font.getDefault().getHeight();
   int preferredWidth = getPreferredWidth();
   Field field = getField(0);
   layoutChild(field, 44, 44);
   setPositionChild(field, 10, getRowHeight() / 4);
   field = getField(1);
   layoutChild(field, preferredWidth - 16, fontHeight + 1);
   setPositionChild(field, 70, getRowHeight() / 5);
   field = getField(2);
   layoutChild(field, field.getPreferredWidth(), fontHeight + 1);
   setPositionChild(field, 70, (getRowHeight() / 2) + 5);
   setExtent(preferredWidth, getPreferredHeight());
  }
  public int getPreferredWidth() {
   return Graphics.getScreenWidth();
  }
  public int getPreferredHeight() {
   return getRowHeight();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Is there an error message? What's TableRowManager?

Comment: what is TableRowManager() in your application.let me know that code then only anybody can help you. so attach your TableRowManager() code also.

Comment: Are you sure you use `ListField`? There is no `ListField` instance in the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

in tableRowManager add this

```
    //for non touch
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                    fieldChangeNotify(0);
                    return true;
                }
//for  touch
                protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
                    if (TouchEvent.CLICK == message.getEvent()) {
                        FieldChangeListener listener = getChangeListener();
                        if (null != listener)
                            listener.fieldChanged(this, 1);
                    }

                    return super.touchEvent(message);
                }
```

try this let me know is it working or not.

Comment: its not working buddy.
Do we have write any other code somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, fieldChangeLister/FieldChanged isnt getting called with ListField UI [as it works for button and labels.]So I think FieldChanged is not supported with Listfield

In navigationClick/TouchEvent (), write the action you are writing in FieldChange method.